# Show $F \otimes_{\mathbb{Q}} F$ is isomorphic to $F \times F(\zeta_3)$, where $F = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, tensor-products

I have tried a few maps but none of them worked. Further since we are tensoring over $\mathbb{Q}$, $F \otimes_{\mathbb{Q}} F$ and $F \times F(\zeta_3)$ do not appear to have the same dimensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They actually DO have same dimension over $\mathbb{Q}$ (since $3^2=3+6$).

Note that, as $F$-algebras, we have $$F\otimes_\mathbb{Q} F\simeq \mathbb{Q}[X]/(X^3-2)\otimes F\simeq F[X]/(X^3-2)\simeq F[X]/(X-\alpha)\times F[X]/(X^2 +\alpha X+ \alpha^2),$$ where $\alpha=\sqrt[3]{2}$, hence $F\otimes F\simeq_\mathbb{Q} F\times F[X]/(X^2 +\alpha X+ \alpha^2)$.

Now the map $X\mapsto \alpha^{-1}X$ yields an isomorphism of $F$-algebras $F[X]/(X^2 +\alpha X+ \alpha^2)\simeq F[X]/(X^2 +X+ 1)$, and we are done since this last quotient is $F$-isomorphic to $F(\zeta_3)$.

Details are left to you as an exercise.